# JQuery .getJSON web scraping locality

Tags: jquery, json, web-scraping

I am trying to pull some data from a website using JQuery .getJSON

I ready upon some articles stating that it will only work with local files.

Indeed, I tried to request a GET method to an outside www link and it never went through. However, if I use Yahoo YQL to collect data from that www URL and then use my JQUery app to get JSON from the YQL link, then it works.

It is however very inconvinient. Is there a way to send a GET request and obtain JSON back from an outside wwww link? (besides going through YQL)?

Answer (score 3):

Nope, the wall you are hitting is Same Origin Policy.

Check if the service supports JSONP, and if it does, use that.

Otherwise either use YQL or proxy the data through your server.

Comment: why is YQL able to get through that? And why am I able to request through YQL?

Comment: @Ethan it makes a request via it's server and then passes it back via JSONP I imagine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way. It is called `JSONP`. Check this out: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/